# Proper description of a polar region in xy plane

Tags: polar-coordinates

If $$0\leq\theta\leq \pi/2, ~~1\leq r\leq 2$$ so which picture is right? I myself selected the one on the right. However, someone preferred to take the other picture because those two line belongs to the mentioned angels.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with polar *functions* $r=f(\theta)$, $r$ may be (and usually is) allowed to go negative. However, when describing *regions* of the plane, conventionally $r$ is always non-negative to avoid a double cover of the $\theta$ parameter space, so the right picture is right.

Comment: Surely the reason that the right hand picture is correct comes more from the given values of $\theta$, both images show $r$ as non negative?

Comment: @MRobinson With $r$ allowed to be non-negative, assuming $\theta$ is kept in a principal range, every point has two representations. I believe it is the desire for uniqueness like the Cartesian system that restricts $r$ to non-negativeness.

Comment: What do you mean by "Principal Range"? I was always taught to consider $r \ge 0$ and $0 \le \theta \le 2\pi$. So the left picture, in that line of thinking, is wrong. But not because of a dependence on $r$ as you suggest?

Comment: @MRobinson principal range: some range of length $2\pi$.

Comment: In that case I agree with your comments, but I am still not sure why your answer states "$r$ is always non-negative, so the right picture is right". If $r$ is non-negative, as we agree, and $\theta$ varies between $0$ and $2\pi$, how are you using the non-negativeness of $r$ to make your distinction?

Comment: @MRobinson actually, if the left interpretation implies double-covering $\theta$ space, which is "unpleasant".

Comment: Exactly, but that isn't the point you made in your answer